# how to see SQL results on flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart

i was wondering if we could see our data base review or something like organize and showing result of the database that we've made like the c# something like this

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that in-app you want to view the database?

Comment: no just something debug and see result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Android Studio` you can see your database using `Database Inspector`

go to the link bellow and follow the steps.

[Read the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database)

Comment: Yes!, Check out this extension 

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite